# SQL query in Android - search for whole or part of a string

Tags: android, sql

I'm not experienced with SQL queries too much so I'm having some trouble in finding the solution to my problem.

I have a list of Bookmarks, for example: Facebook, Developers Console, Stack Overflow...
and I also have a list of their URLs: http://m.facebook.com, https://market.android.com...

I'm trying to let the user search these 2 lists and show any similar result, for example - if the user searched for "face" - I want him to get "Facebook".
And if the user searched for "market" (for the market.android.. URL), he'll get "Developers Console".

This is my SQL WHERE clause:

```
String where = Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE + " LIKE ? OR "
            + Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL + " LIKE ?";

            where = "(" + where + ") AND " + Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + " == 1";
```

It works fine but it only finds complete strings (for example: to find "Facebook", I must search for "Facebook" OR "facebook").

Would love some help with that!

Thanks,
Lior

UPDATE:

Relevant code:

```
//search
            String[] selArgs = new String[] { query };

            String where = Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE + " LIKE '%" + query + "%' OR "
            + Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL + " LIKE '%" + query + "%'";

            where = "(" + where + ") AND " + Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + " == 1";

            cur = managedQuery(BOOKMARKS_URI, projection,
                    where, null, Browser.BookmarkColumns.VISITS + " DESC");
```

Logcat stacktrace:

```
10-23 00:09:59.765: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15101): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-23 00:09:59.765: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15101): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{PACKAGE}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "'%face%) AND bookmark == 1) ORDER BY visits DESC": , while compiling: SELECT _id, title, url, visits, favicon, thumbnail, touch_icon, _id AS _id FROM bookmarks WHERE ((title LIKE '%face%' OR url LIKE '%face%) AND bookmark == 1) ORDER BY visits DESC
10-23 00:09:59.765: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
10-23 00:09:59.765: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
10-23 00:09:59.765: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-23 00:09:59.765: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15101):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
10-23 00:09:59.765: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15101):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-23 00:09:59.765: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15101):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-23 00:09:59.765: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
10-23 00:09:59.765: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15101):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-23 00:09:59.765: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15101):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-23 00:09:59.765: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15101):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
10-23 00:09:59.765: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15101):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
10-23 00:09:59.765: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15101):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-23 00:09:59.765: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15101): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "'%face%) AND bookmark == 1) ORDER BY visits DESC": , while compiling: SELECT _id, title, url, visits, favicon, thumbnail, touch_icon, _id AS _id FROM bookmarks WHERE ((title LIKE '%face%' OR url LIKE '%face%) AND bookmark == 1) ORDER BY visits DESC
10-23 00:09:59.765: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15101):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:158)
10-23 00:09:59.765: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15101):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:114)
10-23 00:09:59.765: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15101):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.bulkQueryInternal(ContentProviderNative.java:330)
10-23 00:09:59.765: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15101):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366)
10-23 00:09:59.765: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15101):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:271)
10-23 00:09:59.765: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15101):     at android.app.Activity.managedQuery(Activity.java:1550)
10-23 00:09:59.765: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15101):     at PACKAGE.doMySearch(APPNAME.java:725)
10-23 00:09:59.765: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15101):     at PACKAGE.onCreate(APPNAME.java:150)
10-23 00:09:59.765: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15101):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-23 00:09:59.765: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
String where = Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE + " LIKE '%" + x +"%' OR "
            + Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL + " LIKE '%" + x +"%'";
            where = "(" + where + ") AND " + Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + " == 1";
```

where x is the text that user has inserted, i.e. face.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Dimitris Makris found the issue. you were missing a ' here " LIKE '%" + x +"%"; and I copy-pasted without noticing. It works now, Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SQL-keyword `LIKE` for this. Encapsulate it with the wildward (%) and you're way to go.

```
sqlite> select * from testtable where name like '%face%';
facebook|42
```